# Download file in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to download a file in my website.

My code:

```
var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/upload/products/");
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

var stream =new FileStream(uploadPath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadPath + "\\" + fileName)
};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return response;
```

But I can't see progress of file download on browser. Please help me!

Comment: Saying `it no working` doesn't really provide much to go on in providing a cause and possible solution. Are you getting any kind of error. Have you inspected the response message (\w something like Fiddler). Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

In case the file stream is being closed before response can be returned you can copy it over to a memory stream and use that.

```
var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/upload/products/");

var stream = new FileStream(uploadPath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
//content length for header
var contentLength = memoryStream.Length;

var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadPath + "\\" + fileName)
};


return response;
```

Comment: I edited my code but I can't see progress of file download on browser. It no working